# Running a kusto query to find servers not reporting in ATP for more than 24 hours does not provide with correct information

Tags: azure, kql, windows-defender

I am trying to get the servers which did not report for more than 24 hours in ATP and running the following, but getting incorrect data:

```
DeviceInfo
| where isnotnull(OSBuild) 
| summarize last_seen = max(Timestamp) by  DeviceId, DeviceName, OSPlatform, OSBuild
| project last_seen, DeviceId, DeviceName, OSPlatform, OSBuild
| where OSPlatform contains "server" //added this line to filter for servers only
| where last_seen > ago(24h)
| sort by last_seen asc
```

Result of query shows not only devices with yesterday's timestamp, but today as well...
Running the query in advanced hunting of Defender ATP.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Aku5.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change:

`| where last_seen > ago(24h)`

To

`| where last_seen < ago(24h)`

Comment: getting a similar result...I would like to narrow it down to devices not seen for more than 24 hours

Comment: That's too strange... When you have a filter `| where last_seen < ago(24h)` you're only supposed to see records in which the value of `last_seen` is smaller than `ago(24h)`. Are you seeing something else..?

Comment: just to make sure we are on the same page...
form the drop down on the right hand side, I have selected 7 days.
run the query and getting devices with last_seen as old as march 3 and new as march 5

Comment: So the query seems to work correctly - indeed the value of last_seen is older than ago(1d). So I don't understand what's missing...

Comment: Hi @Slavik N it seems like the results are coming now, but the issue I am facing is the timestamp, which is not correct.
I am getting a Timestamp in my results which would indicate that my server is not reporting in ATP, but when actually going on the specific server, everything is fine...
I would like to know why such discrepancy...Timezone is setup to local.

Comment: Well, that question should go to ATP... As for ADX/Kusto - the query works fine. The only mistake you had in your query is the usage of '>' instead of '<', as I indicated in my answer. If this helps, please accept the answer. Thanks.